# JIT Debugger only options are new instance of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to debug the seed method of an EF migration.

I've added a `Debugger.Launch()` statement.  When it's run I get the message box to attach:

[image]

But there's no option to use the existing instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: I've seen this before. Only solution I've found so far is to close all open VS instances and restart it. Would like to find a better solution!

Comment: @MarkPim Even that doesn't work for me.  This is really annoying.

Comment: I presume your VS instance isn't already debugging something?

Comment: No, I've just closed them all and reopened one again.  I've restarted the computer as well.

Comment: It is Visual Studio itself that crashed, note how it says "devenv.exe" and not the name of your program.  So sure, it won't offer the crashed program as a debugger option, that's not going to work well.   The odds that you can actually debug such a problem are not fantastic, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me quite frequently.  I use very large Visual Studio solutions that sometimes hang or have other weird behavior.  For instance, if I click the "x" the UI goes away, but there's still a "devenv.exe" from that solution left running.

Usually, killing all devenv.exe and restart will work.  I believe what happens here is that the JIT debugger window (or it's caller) has a timeout for finding VS processes.  If one of your VS processes has hung or is otherwise unresponsive, the timeout occurs and it bails out.  I always notice that the JIT window takes a little longer to popup than normal when this problems manifests.  The extra time length is almost always the same.  That makes me feel fairly confident in my diagnosis.

Thus, I would recommend looking for any stray devenv.exe processes and forcefully killing them.  Also, look to see if any of your VS windows have popups that might block responsiveness.  As a last resort, shut all devenv processes down and restart one.  That always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I know what it is.  The code I'm trying to debug is EF migration code.  I guess, as this is run via the PowerShell context, it is running in the context of `devenv.exe` and so can't be debugger via it.